# naming in cloudformation template from the parameters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to name my security groups with respect to their name but my issue is I also wish to include a group type name. for example:

I tried it as

```
somerdsgroup:
  Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
  Properties: 
    GroupDescription: "RDS Security Group"
    Tags: 
      - 
        key: "env"
        value: Ref: envT
      -
        key:"name"
        value: #here i want like demo-cron

    VpcId: Ref: myVpcid
```

I expect the result to be like 
`name : demo-cron` or `name : dev-cron` depending on the `envT` variable ?

Comment: Assuming the "demo" string is the value of the `envT` variable, can't you just do something like `!Sub ${envT}-cron`?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
somerdsgroup:
  Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
  Properties: 
    GroupDescription: "RDS Security Group"
    Tags: 
      - key: "env"
        value: Ref: envT
      - key:"name"
        value: !Sub "{envT}-${group}"
    VpcId: Ref: myVpcid
```